# Is there Tabulator functionality to maintain the position of an 'edit select list' when scrolling in a nested div?

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

## Problem

When you have a Tabulator table that is nested in a scroll-able div, and click on an autocomplete cell to reveal the 'edit select list', if you now scroll within that div then the the 'edit select list' will move away from its original cell position.

I can see this occurs because the 'edit select list' is a div that is created and appended to the main DOM and thus scrolling on the inner div has no affect on its position.

Is there some option to have the 'edit select list' appended to a local element or the Tabulator element itself so it will scroll with the inner div?

## Working Example

Go to [Tabulators editable example](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.1?#editable), edit a country field cell so multiple options are revealed and then scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid there is no functionality to change how the autocomplete editor is shown.

That being said you can of course add your own [Custom Editor](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/edit#edit-custom) which can be configured in any way you like. You could even use the existing [Autocomplete Editor](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/edit.js#L997) as a starting point